# How to find rectangles in a full transparent object?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, transparent

I have an input image of a fully transparent object:

[image]

I need to detect the 42 rectangles in this image. This is an example of the output image I need (I marked 6 rectangles for better understanding):

[image]

The problem is that the rectangles look really different. I have to use this input image.
How can I achieve this?

Edit 1: Here is a input image as png:

[image]

Comment: Optimize the lighting and background for better and more similar visibility of each of the rectangle. In the given image I would recommend to segment the area between the rectangles, which looks more stable.

Comment: Do you have a higher resolution image without compression artifacts (e.g. png 
or pgm images)?

Comment: I captured another image in the png format. I edited the post.

Comment: Are there always 42 rectangles placed always equally 6*7?

Comment: Yes. There are always 42 rectangles, which are placed 6*7.

Comment: If your image was "fully" transparent, then you would see nothing. I assume you mean there is partial transparency everywhere. Is that correct? Please be careful of your terminology.

Comment: picture needs to be straighter. then some methods (see below) become very accurate. -- png or jpeg doesn't matter. resolution would help, if there is any left to be had.

Answer (score 4):

If you calculate the variance down the rows and across the columns, using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('YOURIMAGE', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Calculate horizontal and vertical variance
h = np.var(im, axis=1)
v = np.var(im, axis=0)
```

You can plot them and hopefully locate the peaks of variance which should be your objects:

[image]

[image]

Comment: A good starting point

Answer (score 1):

Mark Setchell's idea is out-of-the-box. Here is a more traditional approach.

**Approach:**

The image contains boxes whose intensity fades away in the lower rows. Using global equalization would fail here since the intensity changes of the entire image is taken into account. I opted for a local equalization approach in OpenCV this is available as [CLAHE (Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization))](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html)

***Using CLAHE:***

- Equalization is applied on individual regions of the image whose size can be predefined.
- To avoid over amplification, contrast limiting is applied, (hence the name).

Let's see how to use it in our problem:

**Code:**

```
# read image and store green channel
green_channel = img[:,:,1]

# grid-size for CLAHE
ts = 8
# initialize CLAHE function with parameters
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(ts, ts))
# apply the function
cl = clahe.apply(green_channel)
```

[image]

Notice the image above, the boxes in the lower regions appear slightly darker as expected. This will help us later on.

```
# apply Otsu threshold
r,th_cl = cv2.threshold(cl, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

[image]

```
# dilation performed using vertical kernels to connect disjoined boxes
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(th_cl, vertical_kernel, iterations=1)
```

[image]

```
# find contours and draw bounding boxes
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
img2 = img.copy()
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 100:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        img2 = cv2.rectangle(img2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,255,255), 1)
```

[image]

(The top-rightmost box isn't covered properly. You would need to tweak the various parameters to get an accurate result)

**Other pre-processing approaches you can try:**

1. Global equalization
2. Contrast stretching
3. Normalization